# Expected number of fixed points in a permutation by brute force

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, fixed-points

I'm trying to compute the expected value of fixed points in a permutation without using the linearity of expectation.
I tried the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\frac{(n-i)!\binom{n}{i}}{n!}$$
However, this is not working and I don't understand why, as the probability of a permutation with i fixed points is:  $$\frac{(n-i)!\binom{n}{i}}{n!}$$
Which is the number of permutations with i fixed points over the total number of permutations possible.

Comment: No, it isn't because the permutations counted by $(n-i)!$ might have fixed points.

Comment: You formula for the probability of a permutation with i fixed points returns 1 when n=3 and i=1.

Comment: What you should have had is $!(n-i)$ using the *subfactorial*, not $(n-i)!$ using the factorial.  The factorial $k!$ counts the number of permutations of $k$ elements where we don't care about whether it does or does not have fixed points.  The *subfactorial* counts the number of [*derangements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $k$ elements... permutations who have *no* fixed points.

Comment: Now... while it is true that you can get the expression $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\dfrac{!(n-i)\binom{n}{i}}{n!}$ for the expected value... this is hardly useful.  It is very difficult to try to manipulate this expression further to simplify and evaluate the result.  We know that the result happens to equal $1$ exactly through other methods, and so we have as an identity that this sum must equal $1$ as well, but this is generally not found because of simplifications or understanding of the summation as it appears here, but rather by our understanding of the linearity of expectation approach.